# Changing the interpretation on Python Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to change the Interpreter from Python 3.7 to Python 3.6 in Spyder. I have gone to preferences then to Python Interpreter. I click the drop down box but there is nothing there. How do I add Python 3.6 as on option in the drop down?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If so, which one?

Comment: I am using Spyder 3.3.2.

Comment: I am also on a Mac.

Comment: do you have python 3.6 and 3.7 both installed?

Comment: I only have Python 3.7. I didn't see 3.6 as an option on Anaconda, but the online class is using Python 3.6. I need to be able to use keras and tensorflow.

Comment: Also if you don't have conda or any other virtual enviornment, it is advised to install 1 version of python in your system.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [the documentation](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#working-with-other-environments-and-python-installations) we have for this.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Spyder then I assume you have installed Anaconda.

[Unfortunately tensorflow doesnt work in  python 3.7 yet.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022)

To use Tensorflow/Keras: create new environment with python 3.6 and then use them seamlessly.

To create enviroment in conda:
Use `anaconda prompt`/`anaconda navigator` for environment management.
In case of Anaconda Prompt, create environments similar to below code

```
conda create --name env_name python=3.6
```

then to use this environment just created, do:

```
activate env_name  # on windows
source activate env_name # on mac
```

Then if you are done with your works in that environment, deactivate the environment using `deactivate`command in prompt.

```
deactivate # in windows
source deactivate # in mac
```

For more help on environment management visit [this link](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are a life saver!!

Comment: Glad it helped. I had the same issue once I upgraded to Python 3.7 in anaconda.